# Error I dont understand

Tags: javascript, oop

Can anyone correct what Im doing here

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function DataService($scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;

        // Members Area
        var addVessel = function (userId) {
            alert("user"+userId);
        };

    } has no method 'addVessel'
```

Many Thanks - Im new to this

After reviewing the responses it seems the problem is nested higher up

This is the namespace/class

```
// Member Service Namespace
var MemberService;
(function (MemberService) {

// Member service type
var DataService = (function ($scope) {

    // Construct the data service
    function DataService($scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;

        // Members Area
        this.addVessel = function (userId) {
            alert("user"+userId);
        };

    }

    return DataService;
})();
MemberService.DataService = DataService;

})(MemberService || (MemberService = {}));
```

and this is the call

```
MemberService.DataService.addVessel('XXX');
```

Comment: before correcting it, can you tell us what you are doing there? Whhat is the problem? How are you using it ?

Comment: Do you have any more relavent code you could post ?

Comment: Ive changed the local definition to "this" but the problem is the same

Comment: "Error I can't understand" is meaningless when you never tell us what the error is; without that information, we can't understand either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never add the method `addVessel()` to the object, but use it just as a "private" method within the object's scope.

Use this instead:

```
function DataService($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;

    // Members Area
    this.addVessel = function (userId) {
        alert("user"+userId);
    };

}
```

**EDIT**

Your error seems to be, that you create a constructor function with `DataService`, but never actually call this constructor.

So one solution would be to change this line

```
MemberService.DataService = DataService;
```

into

```
MemberService.DataService = new DataService( param );
```

This will create a new instance of your `` `DataService `` and attach this to `MemberService.DataService`.

If you, however, want to create multiple instances, your code would be right so far, but in order to call, you first have to create an object of this constructor:

```
var myService = new MemberService.DataService( param );
```

Comment: Ive changed the local definition to "this" but the problem is the same

Comment: @Herb Work fine for me. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PGWSN/).

Comment: Thanks Sirko - I have edited the post based on your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var addVessel = ...
```

to

```
this.addVessel = ...
```

That should solve it.

In the former case, `addVessel` is a local variable inside the `DataService` function. Whereas in the latter case, it is a member of the function object `DataService` accessible using the dot notation.